# What is the proper way to configure an AWS load balancer over https to a nodejs EBS instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, load-balancing

My current aws setup is below:

custom aws domain --> classic load balancer (which has an attached SSL cert from aws cert manager) --> elastic beanstalk instance

From what I understand about the relationship between a load balancer, and the instance it points to....after configuring a load balancer to point to an instance, you would then use the load balancer's public-facing DNS instead of the ip/dns of the elastic beanstalk instance.

The load balancer also has a ssl cert attached to it, from the AWS certificate manager service. From what I understand about incorporating a SSL cert with a load balancer, you would have someone go to https://, and the load balancer would encrypt and decrypt before communicating with the instance it's pointing to, which is done over port 80 via http.

My load balancer's listener config is below:

[Load Balancer Config Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjFkj.png)

On my elastic beanstalk instance i have a nginx.conf file that supposedly takes traffic over port 80 and reroutes to the port that my node server is running on, like below:

```
server {
  listen 8080;

  location / {
      proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
      proxy_set_header   Connection "";
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

At the moment I'm getting 502 nginx errors. Previously I was getting 508 errors. I haven't gotten a simple endpoint to load at all on my elastic beanstalk instance.

I have seen all the conversations on this topic but none that really help me conclude as to what I'm doing incorrectly. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: I am wondering if you have associated an SSL certificate with your Load Balancer. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49139046/single-instance-elastic-beanstalk-node-app-https-refused-to-connect#comments-49139046) alludes to the option settings that you can add to specify the SSL cert for the LB.

You can set up a cert for a [classic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ssl-server-cert.html) or an [application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html) LB.

Comment: @progfan I do have an SSL certificate associated with my load balancer. I've checked that many times. Still not able to solve this problem.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww why do you comment on other people asking questions about SSL or OpenSSL, and don't complain to them about the content of their question on stackoverflow? My question is related to SSL, and my EBS instance has 'programming' on it that is pertinent to the conclusion of this problem. This is certainly what I would consider to be on topic.